# Matlab Optimisation Fitness Function COCOMO

Tags: algorithm, matlab, math, genetic-algorithm, genetic

I'm trying to calculate the COCOMO Model Parameters using Genetic Algorithm.

This is the first time i'm using Matlab and I have watched a lot of videos on the Optimisation Tool in Matlab. I am not sure how to write the fitness function which have been described in lots of research papers particulary:
[image: com]

Sources : A. F. Sheta, "Estimation of the COCOMO model parameters using
genetic algorithms for NASA software projects," Journal of Computer
Science, vol. 2, no. 2, pp. 118-123,2006.

I need to write the fitness function in Matlab.

```
function z = COCOMO(actual, estimated)

z(1) = (1 - var(actual - estimated)/var(actual)) * 100; %Variance Accounted For

z(2) = 1/N * symsum(mod(actual-estimated)/actual, actual, 1, N); % Mean Magnitude of Related Error

end
```

Any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: help with what?

Comment: @Ander Biguri I need help to write the fitness function and how to run the algorithm in Matlab

Comment: What help do you need? What issue are you facing?

Comment: @Sardar Usama the thing is that Im new to matlab and genetic algorithm. I have read research papers on how researchers have optimised the COCOMO model using Genetic Algorithm. I want to try same in matlab using the Optimisation tool. Any idea how to achieve this ?